# Exporting a void function with Println statements into a TextArea(JavaFx)

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

How can i pass a bunch of `System.out.println()` statements which are in a void function i created, into a `TextArea`? Here is my code so far:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class mycode extends Application {

 private Button b;
 private TextArea a;


@Override
public void start(Stage s) throws Exception{




    s.setTitle("First project");
    HBox root= new HBox();
    Scene sc = new Scene(root,1000,600, Color.AZURE);

    a= new TextArea();
    a.setLayoutX(120);
    a.setLayoutY(3);
    a.setPrefSize(400, 400);
    root.getChildren().add(a);

    s.setScene(sc);
    s.show();



}

public static void main(String []args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

And the void fuction would be like this:

```
  for(int i=0;i<chain.size();i++) {
        System.out.println("Block: " + i);
        System.out.println("Version: " + chain.get(i).getVersion());
        System.out.println("TimeStamp: " + chain.get(i).getTimestamp());
        System.out.println("PreviousHash: " +chain.get(i).getPreviousHash());
        System.out.println("Hash: " + chain.get(i).getHash());
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: Do not use System.out.println.  Use the inherited [appendText](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.html#appendText(java.lang.String)) method instead.  That method does not add a newline, so remember to add `"\n"` to the end of each line in your code.

Comment: @VGR i am not quite following you :/

Comment: Change `System.out.println("Block: " + i)` to `a.appendText("Block: " + i + "\n")`.

Comment: On a related note, I **highly** recommend you work through some JavaFX tutorials. There's quite a bit in your code that could/should be improved.

Comment: @Zephyr thank u for the advice